# Equivalent on Android to Key-Value Observing

Tags: android, cocoa-touch

Is there a technique on Android equivalent to Cocoa Touch's notification center and [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equivalent technique to NSNotificationCenter on android can be implemented via broadcasts and BroadcastReceivers. For more information you should read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers

Answer (score 8):

There's [Property Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html).

Other than that, it's all pretty standard Java, so you'd be tying into EventListeners of one flavor or another.

Answer (score 1):

check the following library which would allow you to achieve such behavior

https://github.com/ahmed-basyouni/AndroidKVO